# is it possible for http server to respond http client on same connection fd each time?

Tags: sockets

I want to write iterative `HTTP server` code that accepts one `HTTP Client` on the same `conn_fd (file descriptor)` every time, but for different clients it should create `new_fd`, based on checking the client address. Is the possible?

Comment: I've posted an answer assuming you're using Linux and C, but you should edit your question to make that info clear

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but this is basically how sockets works: you create a master socket and set it to a listening state. Then, everytime  you accept a new client, a new socket is created for that client, while the master socket remains the same.
For a nice intro about Unix sockets, see http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Answer (score 0):

Each new connection will result in a new socket. So if the same client connects multiple times it will be a new socket (and file descriptor), but if it connects one time and sends multiple requests over the same connection (HTTP keep alive) it will be the same fd.